# import of VS2012 project to monodevelop failes to compile with "CS1566"

Tags: monodevelop

I tried to import a Visual Studio 2012 csproj file to Monodevelop. Everything works fine until I compile. When I compile the project, it generates 1 *.resources file for the first form, but for the following forms, no *.resources files are generated and the compile fails with

> Error reading the resource file ... -- the system can't finde the file (CS1566)

(sorry - I had to translate from German)

How can I fix that?

Regards, Tobias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue, I googled, and I found this link: https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/1751

as it says there, you have to use XBuild in MonoDevelop (go to Tools->Options->Projects->Build). That solved the problem for me.

Comment: to be more precised, in MonoDevelop 3.1.2, it's located under Tools -> Options -> Projects -> Preferences -> Build. Check "Compile projects using MSBuild / XBuild"

Comment: In MonoDevelop 4.0.12, its located under Edit -> Preferences -> Projects -> Build.