# Targeting the MONO Runtime causes Xamarin Build to fail

Tags: windows, xamarin, mono

After creating a simple .NET console application in Xamarin Studio, I can build/debug fine if the default Target Runtime is set to 'Microsoft .NET'.

If I set the runtime to MONO ('Mono 4.0.1'), then my project no longer builds.

The error is:

> Error: Unknown MSBuild failure. Please try building the project again

The build output window shows everything succeeding up until the last line, which displays
**Build: 1 error, 0 warnings**":

Is targeting the MONO Runtime in this way not valid? A related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041236/force-xamarin-to-use-mono-on-windows) indicates that it is...

What am I doing wrong?

Running Windows7 (64 bit), Xamarin Studio 5.9. Mono 4.0.1, .NET 4.5

The build output is as follows:

> Cleaning Solution: XamarinTest (Debug)
>
> Cleaning: XamarinTest (Debug)
>
> Build started 05/08/2015 16:57:03.
>   __________________________________________________ Project "C:\Development\Test\XamarinTest\XamarinTest\XamarinTest.csproj"
>   (Clean target(s)):        Target CoreClean:       Deleting file
>   'C:\Development\Test\XamarinTest\XamarinTest\obj\Debug.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttribute.cs'
>         Deleting file
>   'C:\Development\Test\XamarinTest\XamarinTest\bin\Debug\XamarinTest.dll.mdb'
>         Deleting file
>   'C:\Development\Test\XamarinTest\XamarinTest\bin\Debug\XamarinTest.dll'
>         Deleting file
>   'C:\Development\Test\XamarinTest\XamarinTest\obj\Debug\XamarinTest.dll'
>         Deleting file
>   'C:\Development\Test\XamarinTest\XamarinTest\obj\Debug\XamarinTest.dll.mdb'
>         Deleting file
>   'C:\Development\Test\XamarinTest\XamarinTest\obj\Debug\XamarinTest.csproj.FilesWrittenAbsolute.txt'
>   Done building project
>   "C:\Development\Test\XamarinTest\XamarinTest\XamarinTest.csproj".
>
> Build succeeded.   0 Error(s)      0 Warning(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.1350135
>
> Cleaning: XamConsole (Debug)
>
> Build started 05/08/2015 16:57:04.
>   __________________________________________________ Project "C:\Development\Test\XamarinTest\XamConsole\XamConsole.csproj" (Clean
>   target(s)):       Target CoreClean:       Deleting file
>   'C:\Development\Test\XamarinTest\XamConsole\obj\Debug\XamConsole.exe'
>   Done building project
>   "C:\Development\Test\XamarinTest\XamConsole\XamConsole.csproj".
>
> Build succeeded.   0 Warning(s)    0 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.0170017
>
> Building Solution: XamarinTest (Debug)
>
> Building: XamarinTest (Debug)
>
> Build started 05/08/2015 16:57:04.
>   __________________________________________________ Project "C:\Development\Test\XamarinTest\XamarinTest\XamarinTest.csproj"
>   (Build target(s)):        Target PrepareForBuild:         Configuration: Debug
>   Platform: AnyCPU      Target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:     No input
>   files were specified for target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies, skipping.
>         Target CoreCompile:         Tool C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Mono\lib\mono\4.5\mcs.exe execution started with arguments:
>   /noconfig /debug:full /debug+ /optimize-
>   /out:obj\Debug\XamarinTest.dll MyClass.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
>   obj\Debug.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttribute.cs
>   /target:library /define:DEBUG /nostdlib /reference:"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Mono\lib\mono\4.5..\xbuild-frameworks.NETFramework\v4.5\RedistList........\4.5\System.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Mono\lib\mono\4.5..\xbuild-frameworks.NETFramework\v4.5\RedistList........\4.5\System.Core.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\lib\mono\4.5\mscorlib.dll"
>   /warn:4       Target DeployOutputFiles:       Copying file from
>   'C:\Development\Test\XamarinTest\XamarinTest\obj\Debug\XamarinTest.dll.mdb'
>   to
>   'C:\Development\Test\XamarinTest\XamarinTest\bin\Debug\XamarinTest.dll.mdb'
>         Copying file from
>   'C:\Development\Test\XamarinTest\XamarinTest\obj\Debug\XamarinTest.dll'
>   to
>   'C:\Development\Test\XamarinTest\XamarinTest\bin\Debug\XamarinTest.dll'
>   Done building project
>   "C:\Development\Test\XamarinTest\XamarinTest\XamarinTest.csproj".
>
> Build succeeded.   0 Warning(s)    0 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:08.6528652
>
> ---------------------- Done ----------------------
>
> **Build: 1 error, 0 warnings**

Comment: Me too! I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me, file it at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: Got bitten by that issue also, it seems the bug is tracked [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29901).

Answer (score 4):

Workaround: Uncheck the "Use MSBUild build engine" checkbox. ( Project property => Build => General => Build engine"

It will work.

Comment: I was receiving "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unexpected binary element: 0" with "Use MSBuild..." if my active SDK is a mono 3.x version vs the default 4.x. Builds with xbuild from the cmd-line or via mcs work fine.

Comment: -1. Unchecking "Use MSBUild build engine" results in resource errors. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936650/import-of-vs2012-project-to-monodevelop-failes-to-compile-with-cs1566

Comment: @Nikolai the resolution in the post you link to was to use xbuild instead of msbuild. Not the otherway around

Answer (score 0):

Using prompt, with the command "xbuild" was possible to build.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.  I download Visual Studio 2015 and Fix my problem. All perferct work in VS

Answer (score 0):

I resolve with clean and rebuild solution. 
If it doesn't work, try to close and reopen solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a problem with the file path: having it downloaded from GIT it was like:

```
home/projects/_git/prj%20name
```

Removing the %20 made everything right!

(macos sierra)